How to plot a line with a color gradient
I have 5 different sets of data, where number of points vary. These 5 datasets should be plotted on five lines and for each data in a line should show a heat map or color gradient. the color scheme should be in such a way that global_max should show red and global_min should be as blue. the color of each point should be relevant to its closeness to the global_max or global_min.
I tried this code for one line, but it is more robotic, it is not showing the instataneous (local) coloring but it is arranging the data from highest to lowest which i don't want.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Load the Excel file
file_path = 'data_for_shading.xlsx'  # Replace with your file path
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# Select the column you want to use
column_name = 'HIT_H1'  # Replace with your column name
data = df[column_name].values

# Normalize the data (0 to 1 scale)
norm = (data - np.min(data)) / (np.max(data) - np.min(data))


# Define the colormap (blue to red)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')

# Get colors for each data point
colors = cmap(norm)

# Plot data points on a straight line
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 1))
for i in range(len(data)):
    plt.plot([i, i], [0, 0.1], color=colors[-(i+1)], lw=8)

# Add a color bar to indicate the mapping
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=np.min(data), vmax=np.max(data)))
plt.colorbar(sm, orientation='horizontal', label='Data Value')

# Remove axes and show plot
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

